# Simple C# registry object with Getters and Setters

Tags: c#, object, registry, setter, getter

How would I achieve something like this in C#?

```
object Registry;
Registry = MyProj.Registry.Instance;

int Value;
Value = 15;
Registry.Value = Value; /* Sets it to 15 */
Value = 25;
Value = Registry.Value; /* Returns the 15 */
```

So far I have this object:

```
namespace MyProj
{
    internal sealed class Registry
    {
        static readonly Registry instance = new Registry();

        static Registry()
        {
        }

        Registry()
        {
        }

        public static Registry Instance
        {
            get
            {
                return instance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the question about the windows registry or is the 'Regsitry' name just a conincidence?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add a property to your Registry class:

```
internal sealed class Registry
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Then use like this:

```
Registry theRegistry = MyProj.Registry.Instance;
//note: do not use object as in your question

int value = 15;
theRegistry.Value = value; /* Sets it to 15 */
value = 25;
value = theRegistry.Value; /* Returns the 15 */
```

Comment: @Thomas: make what static?

Registry is a singleton. The Value property is an instance property accessed via the static Registry.Instance property.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the [Microsoft.Win32.Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx) class.  It, and the related classes, have all you need to work with the Windows registry.